# Noether Normalisation lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How do we explain Noether normalisation in terms of line bundles and linear systems?

If $X$ is a smooth irreducible projective variety over an algebraically closed field of char 0 of dimension $r$.

By Noether normalisation, we have a finite surjective (hence flat) morphism $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^r$.

Consider $L$ a very ample line bundle on $X$. Suppose $h^0(X,L)= n+1$. Therefore we have an embedding $X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$. Does this map give a morphism like $f$. That is can we select $r+1$ sections of $H^0(X,L)$ to define a finite surjective morphism from $X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^r$?

What will the degree of such a morphism be?

Comment: Why does $f$ have to be flat? It seems like you must be using something more than finite + surjective. I think there is an old post by Emerton on MO that you could search for.

Comment: These are standard. If $L$ is a globally generated line bundle (neither smoothness nor very ampleness is required) over $X$ of dimension $r$, then we can choose general $r+1$ sections of $L$ which will generate it. Thus, if $X$ is projective and $L$ ample, you get a finite morphism $f$ as above with $f^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^r}(1))=L$ and so the degree of this morphism is just $L^r$, the intersection number.

Comment: @Hoot If $X$ is smooth, then the map is flat.

Comment: @Hoot, exercise III 9.3(a) in Hartshorne's says, if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a finite surjective morphism of non-singular varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$, then $f$ is flat. We can use that right?

Comment: @Mohan, thank you! We therefore get finite surjective morphisms for every ample globally generated $L$ right? What is the relationship between these morphisms?

Comment: @Mohan Whoops! I read too quickly and didn't notice the smoothness. It doesn't seem to be necessary, in any case.

Comment: I am not sure what relationships do you expect. For different line bundles, you get different morphisms and there is no immediate relationship.